# Userform and multiple images

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a sheet which looks up a database which has paths to all available images for a certain code. What I want to do is when the user types in a code into the excel spreadsheet, it creates a button to the right of the table on the same row (easy enough) but then clicking that button brings up the user form. On this userform, I am wanting to list all the images on the database that match that code. Some codes may have 1 image and some as many as 5. I also want each of these labelled 1 to x (with x being the final image).

Once I have that, I want to be able to either have a user click one or more images to add them to the excel sheet (by number reference, so if a user clicks 1, 3 and 4 I want it to put "1, 3, 4" in the cell next to the code). Either that or I may just have them click cancel and manually put in the numbers.

Is what I am wanting possible? How would I go about it? I have absolutely zero experience with User Forms in VBA but really want to see what they are capable of.

Comment: with no programming knowledge I recommend hiring someone

Comment: Thats not what I said. I have plenty of VBA knowledge, just none on User Forms as I have never seen the need to use them. I could do this within the excel sheet quite easily (its how its done in the old version of this file) but want to make it a little neater and nicer this time round

Comment: Not to be too mean but this is a problem that requires a lot of time to solve. I would suggest hiring someone for the job but if you don't want to, I suggest looking into OCR to "read" the image. You will realize it's not easy at all to be 100% accurate or even close to 90%.

Comment: @bmgh1985 "its how its done in the old version of this file" the excel actually read the image and matched your code to the image?? maybe there's a built-in function that I don't know about! D:

Comment: Why don't you try something first and come back with a specific question? Answering code/specific questions is a lot easier.

Comment: Its not so much a "solution" I am after, just some pointing in the direction as to methods I could use to get it done (and something that once I have got it done, I can post up here and potentially help other people further down the line)

Comment: @bmgh1985 why don't you realize that your question is far too broad, partially opinion based, and youre lucky it isn't yet closed. What is your specific question?

Comment: @kpark91 its quite easy to use a bit of VBA to look up a filepath in a database based on a code entered and display the filepath pulled from that database in a cell range. Its doing that in a Userform that I am not entirely sure on

Comment: @bmgh1985 [How to create userform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853685/how-to-create-an-user-interface-userform-in-excel-vba/16854404#16854404)

Comment: @mehow firstly, one question is why try to flame me. Enough on that though. My actual question is does anyone have any insight into doing similar, is it possible, is it easy and is there anything relevant anyone can point me towards?

Comment: @bmgh1985 I am sorry your question is out of scope for SO. You do not ask for opinions and hint about how to go about an entire project.

Comment: @mehow OK thanks for that. A step in the right direction. Unfortunately that is still just basics which I already have a grasp of. Digging a few links through that link though and I am finding some more useful information and while nothing I can use directly, it has given me an idea into how I can get at least part of it done

Comment: OK, the main thing I am stuck on is making the userform "self-aware". If there are 4 images to add, I want it to display 4 images. If there are then 2, then I dont want 2 images and 2 blank boxes, just 2 images.

Comment: @bmgh1985 we can't recommend libraries on SO but the way to go would be to find one that displays images based on parameter telling how many. You can write your own pseudo framework for it

Comment: @mehow ah yes, I hadnt thought of using other libraries actually. Thanks for that idea.

Comment: @bmgh1985 oh. I had understood you question totally differently. I thought the code would need to **match** whatever is written on the image. That would require an OCR technique which allows you to optically recognize characters for matching and OCR is very hard to get it right (you would also need "fuzzy match" since OCR is not 100% accurate). In the end, my bad!

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question:

Yes, it's possible.  Quite simple even from a VBA and UserForms standpoint.

I would go about it by creating a UserForm and adding controls to it, specifically `Image`, `CheckBox`, and `CommandButton` controls.  Once you get a feel for adding them manually, you can write some fairly basic code to add them to the UserForm dynamically and assigning event handlers to them to take care of the user interaction that you want.
As a hint:  double-clicking a control on the UserForm will generate a handler for the default event for that control and take you to the code-behind page for that UserForm.

[image]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917908/programatically-adding-a-commandbutton-to-a-userform) gives some help on programmatically adding controls to a UserForm.

Comment: Hadnt even occurred to me to use checkboxes. I assumed the images themselves would have been the actionable object. Makes things a lot simpler! Just need to figure out changing numbers of images and I am set, thanks :)

Comment: @bmgh1985 I believe there's a functionality in the image object that you can assign a value to.. It requires that for each image, a `click()` event has to be written. But then again, I think using checkboxes is the right choice despite more number of objects you need to create since you don't need to write an event when creating an image.

Answer (score 1):

Ben, I think this is worth pursuing if you have time to play with it some. You'll have to setup the userform. This isn't difficult, but if you have little experience with it you'll have familiarize yourself a bit.

I'd recommend starting with a copy of your spreadsheet, and play with a userform on it. In VBA editor, go to Insert, UserForm. The available controls will pop up in a toolbox window, and if you press F4 you'll see the properties for what you've clicked on. To see a description of these properties, you can go to help from within VBA editor and open the table of contents. Drill down on the TOC on the left through "Visual Basic for Applications Language Reference", "Microsoft Forms Visual Basic Reference", "Reference", "Properties." This will provide a description of properties available for each part of the form (ie "Hidden" for the button you want to place at the end of the row).

For clicking on the images, a suggestion would be to put a description of each image (or just the image name) in a listbox, so the user can choose.

A good starting reference for what is possible is found at [excel-spreadsheet.com](http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/userforms.htm). Of course there are multiple other free sites and helps.

Comment: [stick your spreadsheet on a userform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406319/display-a-part-of-an-excel-sheet-on-a-userform-using-vba/17407415#17407415)